# Apply bookmarkable URL to h:commandLink

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, bookmarks, commandlink

As I read in docs and tried myself, JSF 2.0 applied bookmarkable urls to `h:link` and `h:button` elements.

Is it possible to make bookmarkable URL for `h:commandLink` element? I experience that `f:param` is not applied to the result URL of `h:commandLink`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h:commandLink` fires a POST request, so no, it's not possible. Just use `h:link`.

If the sole reason of using `h:commandLink` is that you'd like to fire a bean action method, then just move that to the bean constructor or `@PostConstruct` of a request scoped bean which is attachted to the view which is opened by `h:link`. You can access `f:param` values by `@ManagedProperty`.

```
public BeanOfTargetPage {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.foo}")
    private String foo;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Parameter 'foo' is available here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: yes,this commandLink invoked method on backend(in sessions scoped bean).What do you mean under request scoped bean attached for view?Should i create one more bean?This commandLink except of method firing, redirects user to other page(/details.jsf).

Comment: The `details.jsf` page get the data from a request scoped bean, right? Just do the `@PostConstruct` job as illustrated in my answer in this bean.

Comment: details.jsf gets data from SessionScoped bean

Comment: Then create another request scoped bean and make the session scoped bean a managed property of the request scoped bean so that you have access to it from in the request scoped bean.

Comment: No, it's only for URL rewriting. It doesn't turn POST actions into GET actions like as you basically want.

Comment: BalusC,thank you for idea. Looks like working.I've done as you advised with one more thing-added outcome string to RequestScoped bean method, string looks like "details?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true",according to PRG pattern.Is it ok solution?

Comment: looks loke it's not,that i need,because if to go by this permalink,that it forwards to already remembered page in cache